# Spring MVC - parse date and show binding errors

Tags: spring, date, spring-mvc, binding

In a Spring MVC controller, I want to parse a `Date` from a request using `@DateTimeFormat` and, in the case of a parsing error, I want to display an error message in my view indicating that the date is invalid.

Here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(
    @ModelAttribute 
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date, 
    BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(result.toString()); // (1)
    }
    System.out.println(date); // (2)

    return "home";
}
```

What I **expect**:

"Happy case" (for `date=1999-10-24`): I expect `(2)` to print the date.

"Error case" (unparseable date): I expect `(1)` to print details about the parsing failure.

What is **actually happening**:

"Happy case" (for `date=1999-10-24`): `(1)` prints a rejected value and `(2)` prints the correctly parsed date:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'date' on field 'date': rejected value [1999-10-24]; ...
Sun Oct 24 00:00:00 CEST 1999
```

"Error case": I see a `400 Bad Request` in the browser

```
Wed Oct 28 20:57:54 CET 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date';
```

I can reproduce this with Spring Boot 1.2.7.RELEASE.

Link to example: https://github.com/shaehnel/spring-mvc-date

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Try to give the model attribute a name; `...@ModelAttribute("date")...`

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is so strange, that I believe something else is going wrong. It the code that you posted really the one that you tested, or did you modified them for the stackoverflow post?

Comment: I have moved my sample application to Github for everyone to verify the behavior and I added the link to my question. The sample is a plain getting started Spring boot application where I added the controller method shown above. I am not aware of having configured anything else in Spring MVC.

Comment: The problem is reproduceable with the example shown on GitHub. It appears that for the latter "hello" case an exception occurs before http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html can act. For the first case it appears there is some incorrect handling of an internal exception which gets recorded, even though the conversion is actually successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your code and confirm that I observed the same behaviour. This behaviour is unexpected but on the other hand I have not found* any hint that it is possible to combine format annotations with `@ModelAttribute` parameters.

So my "workaround" is to use a command object instead of `@ModelAttribute` parameters.

```
public static class MyCommandObject {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {return date;}
    public void setDate(Date date) {this.date = date;}
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(@Valid MyCommandObject myCommandObject, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(result.toString()); 
    }
    System.out.println(myCommandObject.date);

    return "home";
}
```

**I have not found, mean that I was unable to find it, it does not mean that it does not exist. -- It would been nice if someone could confirm hat this just a missing features or real bug.*

Comment: Many thanks for trying my example and showing this workaround! I am still a bit confused as some examples show a similar approach working with different annotations like `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`, see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/convert/ConvertController.java